# transposing large datasets with set structure using formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I am trying to find a way of tranposing large datasets (the structure is shown below) in a certain way and wondering how to implement it in Excel using a formula as to avoid time-consuming and error prone copy-paste transpose!

I want to do the transformation of the data on `sheet A` on a separate sheet (`B`). I essentially have triplicate measurements multiple features of different groups. The number of groups can vary but the measurements will always be in triplicate.
Thanks for any help you can give

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around a bit with the `INDEX`, `COLUMN` and `ROW` formulas and some arithmetic. `INDEX` will look up a cell's value for you, given a row and column number. For a simple transpose, you just need the `COLUMN` of the current cell as the row and the `ROW` of the current cell as the column. However, your operation is slightly more difficult than a simple transposition and therefore we need some arithmetic. With some trial and error I arrived at the formula below.

Provided that Sheet A contains the data in the top left corner (i.e. B2 contains the value 5), this formula on Sheet B will work:

```
=INDEX('Sheet A'!$1:$1048576, MOD(COLUMN()+1,3)+3*ROW()-4, 1+(COLUMN()+1)/3)
```

[image]

Column numbers start at 1, so the `MOD(COLUMN()+1,3)` gives 0 for the Group*n*A-columns, 1 for B and 2 for C. The `3*ROW()` part correspond to the three rows for each Group*n* in Sheet A. The `1+(COLUMN()+1)/3` maps all Cat 1 columns in Sheet B to column 2 in Sheet A, Cat 2 to column 3, etc.

Comment: That worked perfect. Thanks for that, it is really useful and adaptable and saves a lot of copy and pasting.